# Passing dataframe column name to custom function that uses survival::Surv

Tags: r, dplyr, survival

I'm getting the error `Error in Surv(tte, eventfl) : object 'pfstte' not found`, which is because it's not evaluating custom function's (`hrdf`) input parameters because they are column names of the `indf` dataframe. How do I pass a dataframe's column names into a custom function? I tried `{{}}`, `[[]]`, `eval()`, and `substitute`, but none of these worked. Thanks!

```
hrdf <- function(indf, tte, eventfl) {
  
  df <- broom::tidy(coxph(Surv(tte, eventfl) ~ ENRLARM_STD, data = indf[indf$SEX == 'Female',], ties = 'efron'), conf.int = T) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(term = 'Sex', cat = 'Female')
  return(df)
}
```

Comment: why not try incorporating `with` structure? e.g., `with(indf, {broom::tidy(...`

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, but I found a work around using a different approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `Surv(tte, eventfl)` portion by the following:

```
Surv(eval(parse(text = tte)), eval(parse(text = eventfl)))
```

I believe that should do the trick if you then pass the inputs `tte` and `eventfl` to your function `hrdf()` as strings.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, but I found a work around using a different approach. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Maybe you could post your workaround as an answer so that other users may benefit from it?